# What Star Trek episodes (any series) have been censored?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-enterprise

I just came across this:

> At one point, Data makes a reference to the Irish Reunification of 2024, and because of that, the BBC refused to air the episode. It didn’t air on the U.K. government’s station until 2007, though it did air on satellite and cable (sometimes with that reference cut), and was released unedited on DVD in the U.K.

[Star Trek: The Next Generation Rewatch: “The High Ground”  |  Tor.com](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2011/12/star-trek-the-next-generation-rewatch-the-high-ground)

The episode was Star Trek: The Next Generation, *The High Ground*, the one where Dr Crusher is abducted by "terrorists".

Since Star Trek has always touched upon "touchy" subjects, I'm curious about any other examples of government censorship of Star Trek.

Comment: I really enjoyed the anecdote about how William Shatner forced the studio's hand on the first inter-racial kiss depicted on TV.  Had you heard it?  It is discussed in another question about these parts.

Comment: You mean this question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28914/did-kirk-and-uhura-actually-kiss?

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_Stepchildren. Btw, I wasn't aware of the fact that this episode was withdrawn by the BBC in the UK because of 'sadistic plot elements' during the initial run in 1971 and was not shown until a repeat run in January 1994.

Comment: @UwF  Strangely, no that is not the one!  I distinctly recall it included an image of the face Shatner made as he turned away from the Director's sight.  He 'pulled faces at the camera' to sabotage their intended 'altered take' where he simply hugged Uhuru.  Just the image of him doing that made me ROTFL.  Unfortunately my 'search-fu' has taken the night off, for I could not locate it..  :(

Comment: @Andrew Ok, then this one isn't the right one, either, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10789/the-first-sf-or-fantasy-interracial-relationship. Too bad.

Comment: @UwF No, that isn't either.  I also hang out on http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ and although there are various mentions of Kirk, it's not there as far as I can see. :( Maybe I'm misremembering and it was simply that a question linked to an off-site discussion/page.  I'm not sure..

Comment: You probably want examples of censorship for content reasons, but viewers should realize that old TV shows like *Star Trek* are routinely edited and sped up for length so more commercials can be added today.  *Trek* ran for 51 minutes out of an hour broadcast when it was first run.  Programs run around forty-three minutes today.

Comment: “the U.K. government’s station” — just to nit-pick the quote, the BBC is independent of (and often in conflict with) the UK government.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite To further pick at your nit (in turn picking at someone else's...oh, you get the idea), while the BBC is not *overtly* state controlled , it is very much beholden to the "goodwill" of the government of the day. Control is exercised mainly through the collection of licence fees (which are levied on TV set owners but the quantum of which is decided upon by the government) and the appointment of the board of governors (the Thatcher administration was accused of undue influence this way). He who pays the piper calls the tune. So the Beeb is not fully independent.

Comment: @Deepak: sure, although “He who pays the piper calls the tune. So the Beeb is not fully independent.” — well, *we* pay them. The government sets the price and the courts enforce collection of payment, but then ultimately the courts enforce collections of all payments.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, what if the government decided to punish the BBC by cutting the fee drastically? And you haven't addressed my point about the Governors (I'm honestly unsure about the power they hold, but unless it's trivial, it's cause for concern).

Comment: @Deepak: I suspect the middle-classes would revolt! But you’re quite right: the government certainly has more touch points with the BBC than it does with other broadcasters.

Comment: Seems I am in a privileged market  (Canada) - never encountered examples of censorship as either edited or unaired episodes, unless you count Jolene Blalock's nudity - she seems to be nude in at least one scene, but with her back to the camera. No idea what anyone on set might have had the opportunity to see during shooting.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the BBC. not airing the episode was due to specifically   the 1988-1994 Broadcasting ban on pro-IRA broadcasts. Later satellite broadcast of the episode were after the repeal of this and did not face legal sanction for the station broadcasting it.

Comment: Wasn't the DS9 episode, *The Siege of AR-558*, censored in some countries because it depicted violence and the psychological impact of combat stress? I read that viewers in some countries were unaware why Nog had lost a leg when they first saw the later episode, *It's Only a Paper Moon*.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Several episodes of Trek have been censored or simply not shown over the years. Assuming your question relates to the UK, then four instances are notable;

TOS : [The Empath](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Empath_%28episode%29), [Whom the Gods Destroy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Whom_Gods_Destroy_%28episode%29), [Plato's Stepchildren](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Plato%27s_Stepchildren_%28episode%29) and [Miri](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Miri_%28episode%29) were all removed from the broadcast schedule for over 10 years due to containing subjects of "*madness, torture, sadism and disease*" in a show that the BBC considered to be intended for children.

[image: BBC letter]

Additionally, "violent images" were removed from certain episode including TNG: "[Conspiracy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Conspiracy_%28episode%29)" (showing the aftermath of Remick being shot with phasers by Picard and Riker), TNG: "[The Icarus Factor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Icarus_Factor)" (in which Worf is repeatedly hit with Klingon '[painstiks](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Painstik)') and the removal of a line from "[The High Ground](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_High_Ground_%28episode%29)" which relates to Irish reunification.

[image: Worf hit with Pain Sticks] [image: Remick aftermath from Icarus Factor]

Comment: FWIW, I'm interested in any government censorship, not just UK. Very interesting response.

Comment: It's also interesting, and somewhat bizarre, that anyone, anywhere, anytime would think of Star Trek as a "children's show".

Comment: The BBC has a long history of considering anything genre-based to be essentially intended for kids

Comment: @Jolenealaska I watched it as a kid. I will definitely watch it with any child in my care. Kids are basically tiny adults who need to learn - sparking the imagination is just a bonus.

Comment: @Dacio It's a great show for kids, I watch it with kids too. It's just not specifically *for* kids. It's written for adults.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: I glanced at the first Star Wars movie on TV the other day. There's a scene where Luke Skywalker finds the burned but recognizable remains of his parents. It would be _very_ odd to see that in a movie intended for children today.

Comment: Thanks in large part to the tremendous acting by Sir Stewart, I find the torture scenes in Chain of Command much more disturbing than the scenes of those pictures.

Comment: Speaking of disturbing episodes that should have been censored... http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111112213654/startrek/images/3/3c/Profit_and_Lace.jpg

Comment: @Richard re: "smouldering corpse" are you sure that's not a retcon joke?  America has increasingly adopted a bizarre form of political correctness in my lifetime but that seems pretty harsh even for the time.

Comment: @mr.wizard - They're fake.

Comment: @Valorum - indeed, I believe even Blake's 7 was considered to be intended for kids...

Comment: I'm rewatching with my kids, but skipped "Conspiracy"

Comment: @Jolenealaska Nitpick: the honorific ‘[Sir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir)’ is used _only_ before the given name: ‘Sir Patrick’, or ‘Sir Patrick Stewart’. (‘Sir Stewart’ could refer to e.g. Sir Stewart Menzies, head of MI6 during WW2; but not to Sir Patrick. In that respect, it's the opposite of ‘[Lord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord)’, which is mostly used with only the surname. So when Laurence Olivier was made a Baron, he became ‘(The) Lord Olivier’.) — But yes, I agree that Chain Of Command part 2 is an extraordinarily powerful episode thanks to his performance and David Warner's.

Answer (score 33):

The episode "Patterns of Force" (Star Trek: The Original Series, see [Patterns of Force - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patterns_of_Force_%28Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series%29)) from February 16, 1968 was banned in Germany from 1968 until 1995 due to the depiction of Nazi symbols and Nazi uniforms. It was finally shown on German pay TV in 1996. When ZDF showed it for the first time on a public network channel - in 2011, more than 40 years after it was filmed, it was not on until after 10pm - and viewers were warned that no-one under the age of 16 should see it.

See also [Germans boldy show Nazi Star Trek episode 43 years after it was first filmed | *Daily Mail Online*](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2057908/Germans-boldy-Nazi-Star-Trek-episode-43-years-filmed.html).

Comment: As Spock would say, "fascinating". 1995, 1996 and 2011??? wow

Comment: Yes, 1995 on video, 1996 on pay TV, 2011 on a public channel. The Swastika and other symbols of Nazi organisations are illegal in Germany (see, in German, http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verwenden_von_Kennzeichen_verfassungswidriger_Organisationen, or, in English, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafgesetzbuch_section_86a). But I don't quite understand how this would have changed in the mid-nineties. Maybe it would have been legally possible to show this episode much earlier...

Comment: There's an exception for depicting the emblems in a documenting/art context. Movies, TV series, etc. are considered art in these regards; just not video games (unfortunately). So there was literally no legal reason not to show that episode far earlier (at least as far as I know). There've been similar concerns regarding *Hogan's Heroes*, which premiered in Germany some time during the 90's. Back to this episode: I think one of the reasons might have been the conclusion of the episode, which shows the planet's leader as "not that bad guy".

Comment: @Mario Yes, there are exceptions for "acts serving to further civil enlightenment, to avert unconstitutional aims, to promote art or science, research or teaching, reporting about current historical events or similar purposes", but interpreting laws is not an exact science. Take for example the discussion in 2005-2006, when a judge applied the law to Anti-fascism symbols (which contained, e.g. broken swastikas). For me it is still not clear whether the decision not to show this episode in the sixties and seventies was due to fear of legal consequences or public reaction.

Comment: Back then the public stations (especially the ZDF) were rather "conservative" and censored lots of stuff prematurely, for the TV audience because they "cared". One example would be the [heavily cut/censored airing of *Omen 2*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s21cRQJDft0&t=1m13s) in 1984. The interesting part is the fact that the opener is probably more disturbing than the whole movie, especially in this version. ;)

Comment: It should be noted that this episode is still not shown in the continous reruns to TOS. I'm not even sure it was sync'ed..

Comment: Maybe the German version of TOS: *Amok Time* should be noted here, as well. While the reasons are somewhat subject to speculation, the German version basically tells a different story than the original one.

Answer (score 22):

Outside of the UK, the *DS9* episode [*Rejoined*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rejoined_%28episode%29) and *TOS* episode [*Plato's Stepchildren*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Plato%27s_Stepchildren_%28episode%29) were both censored in several markets due to homosexual and interracial kissing, respectively. There were also instances in *TOS* where Roddenberry was forced by Paramount to drop, add, or change certain lines of dialogue, notably the episode [*Who Mourns for Adonais?*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Who_Mourns_for_Adonais?_%28episode%29), in which one of Kirk's lines was altered from (this is from memory, so I may be off slightly) "Humanity no longer needs gods!" to the more [middle-America-friendly](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/33.htm) "Mankind has no need for gods. We find the one quite adequate."

Outside of the major coastal networks in the US, various local affiliates would censor, cut from and (rarely) add to existing episodes as their whims dictated, to the point where for everyone outside of California and the American East Coast could only see full episodes at sci-fi conventions.

I am unaware, however, of any government censorship of *Star Trek* outside of the previously noted British examples. I am certain, however, that certain unsavoury regimes have doubtless censored *Star Trek*, much as they've censored other television programs in the past.

Comment: The second part of the quote was "We find the one quite sufficient". I'm less certain about the first half.

Comment: Strictly speaking the BBC is not "government".

Comment: @ Martin - I did think that it was an odd expression but you can easily see how someone could make that mistake given that it's essentially funded by a form of taxation.

Comment: @Valorum: But then, the same applies to the German *Patterns of Force* example (ZDF being funded by what could be called "a form of taxation", as well).

Answer (score 13):

According to Memory Alpha, a scene in the episode ["Harbinger"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Harbinger_%28episode%29) (*Enterprise*) was visually altered by UPN on its original airing to "crop out" Jolene Blalock's nudity.

The link above has a (slightly NSFW) picture if you wish to be fully informed on the subject.  :)

---

Edit: just noticed that the question specifically asks for examples of government censorship. I'll leave this answer up and let the votes decide if it applies.

Comment: I think it should apply, since most governments don't exercise direct editorial control over TV networks (not even the BBC). The way "government censorship" usually works is through broadcasting standards, anti-obscenity laws and tacit agreements with industry for self-censorship (e.g. the the MPAA and ESRB). So it's up to each network or industry censorship board to apply those legal or implied standards to the broadcasts/publications they oversee. Only in very few cases are government officials able to intervene directly and demand a specific work be censored.

Answer (score 1):

The DS9 episode Rejoined (if that's the one that showed Jadzia kissing another lady Trill) wasn't cut where I saw it but was preceded with a 'the following program contains' kind of warning- is that included in your definition of censorship?

Comment: That episode was in fact censored in certain regions in the U.S. What you saw was probably an alternative route your local network took to avoid censoring it. But "Rejoined" was already mentioned in James Sheridan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In ["Phantasms"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phantasms_(episode)), the scene in which Data stabs Troi in the shoulder was censored in certain countries.

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: Is that the same one where Data sees her as a cake?

Comment: Yes, it is the one where he sees her as a cake. 

Why it was censored? Because some thought it was shocking to see a woman being stabbed.

Why he stabbed her? He was subconsciously aware of a parasite on her shoulder.